# Best way to get Azure and local SQL Server development databases to sync on request

Tags: sql-server, azure, azure-data-studio

I'm looking for a one click system that doesn't require one to delete the Azure database, publish from the local server, and re-create the user info onto the deployment.

What currently works:

1. Drop existing Azure database.
2. MSDeploy the database to azure.
3. Move the database to the app pool
4. Configure Azure database user/access

I briefly looked into the Azure sync, but that doesn't seem like something one can use "on request". Do correct me with example if I'm wrong on this assumption.

The ideal solution would be a one button click from Azure Data Studio to push any and all changes from the (localdb) database to the live one.

Comment: To great extent, SQL Database project type in VS can get you this.

Comment: any link or ideas of what you mean? I have never managed to get EFcore or anything much to successfully talk to azure from within VS.
Generally that's by design since the permissions on the azure side are set to read only...
Though I could see this working as an option with migrations and a specially configured connection line for instance.

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/ssdt/how-to-create-a-new-database-project

Answer (score 0):

Azure Data Studio doesn't provide any readymade **Single Click** data transmission feature from local to cloud or vice-versa.

> Azure Data Studio offers a modern editor experience with IntelliSense,
> code snippets, source control integration, and an integrated terminal.
> It's engineered with the data platform user in mind, with the built-in
> charting of query result sets and customizable dashboards.

It doesn't provide in-built data push feature. Either you should use any programming language to build a dashboard as per your requirement, or you need to use Store Procedure for it.